# Difference between tracking_uri and the backend store uri in MLFLOW

Tags: uri, tracking, mlflow, mlops

I am using Mlflow for my project hosting it in an EC2 instance. I was wondering in MlFlow what is the difference between the backend_store_uri we set when we launch the server and the trarcking_uri ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tracking_uri` is the URL of the MLflow server (remote, or built-in in Databricks) that will be used to log metadata & model (see [doc](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/quickstart.html#launch-a-tracking-server-on-a-remote-machine)).  In your case, this will be the URL pointing to your EC2 instance that should be configured in programs that will log parameters into your server.

`backend_store_uri` - is used by MLflow server to configure where to store this data - on filesystem, in SQL-compatible database, etc. (see [doc](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/cli.html#cmdoption-mlflow-server-backend-store-uri)). If you use SQL database, then you also need to provide the `--default-artifact-root` option to point where to store generated artifacts (images, model files, etc.)

Comment: Thanks ! Yes that is how I use it with this url and with an sqlite db stored in my EC2 machine. It works fine when I try to load a model from my ec2 with mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(
                    model_uri=f"models:/{model_name}/{stage}") but from another ec2 I have this error HTTPConnectionPool(host='ec2_ip', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/2.0/preview/mlflow/registered-models/get-latest-versions?name=model&stages=Staging (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object : Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Comment: I think that it's a networking problem - check firewall/network security groups that they allow port 5000 access